# Remove the intersections of multiple regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

```
 Pattern[] a =new Pattern[2];
 a[0] = Pattern.compile("[$£€]?\\s*\\d*[\\.]?[pP]?\\d*\\d");
 a[1] = Pattern.compile("Rs[.]?\\s*[\\d,]*[.]?\\d*\\d");
```

Ex: `Rs.150` is detected by `a[1]` and `150` is detected by `a[0]`.
How to remove such intersections and let it only detect by `a[1]` but not by `a[0]`?

Comment: The only way to do that would be to make `a[1]` the _first_ regex...

Comment: @fge: What about negative lookahead?

Comment: @krlmlr that would probably be a negative lookbehind on `a[0]` which is needed here, but more details are needed; what does OP want to achieve? Smells like an XY problem again

Comment: Run the regular expression after a small initial test on the string. That does not necessarily have to be solved using regular expressions by itself. Split up the problem space...

Comment: Can you add some inputs to your question ? (ie Rs.150 => MATCH...)

Comment: Are you using these regular expression `Pattern` instances in a search? Because `"Rs.150"` certainly is not matched by a[0], even though `"150"` is.

Comment: Closing as the asker is not responding, and without more info this turns into a flame war.

Comment: @Alex (Rs.150 Match for a[0] but 150 match for a[1] )

Comment: @hitish Check my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149322/363573

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `|` operator inside your regular expression. Then call the method [Matcher#group(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) to see which pattern your input applies to. This method returns `null` if the matching group is empty.

### Sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Build regexp
    final String MONEY_REGEX = "[$£€]?\\s*\\d*[\\.]?[pP]?\\d*\\d";
    final String RS_REGEX = "Rs[.]?\\s*[\\d,]*[.]?\\d*\\d";

    // Separate them with '|' operator and wrap them in two distinct matching groups
    final String MONEY_OR_RS = String.format("(%s)|(%s)", MONEY_REGEX, RS_REGEX);

    // Prepare some sample inputs
    String[] inputs = new String[] { "$100", "Rs.150", "foo" };

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(MONEY_OR_RS);

    // Test each inputs
    Matcher m = null;
    for (String input : inputs) {
        if (m == null) {
            m = p.matcher(input);
        } else {
            m.reset(input);
        }

        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("m.group(0) => %s\nm.group(1) => %s\n", m.group(1), m.group(2)));
        } else {
            System.out.println(input + " doesn't match regexp.");
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
    m.group(0) => $100
    m.group(1) => null

    m.group(0) => null
    m.group(1) => Rs.150

    foo doesn't match regexp.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an initial test to switch between expressions. How fast and/or smart this initial test is is up to you.

In this case you could do something like:

```
if (input.startsWith("Rs.") && a[1].matcher(input).matches()) {
    return true;
}
```

and put it in front of your method that does the testing.

Simply putting the most common regular expressions in front of the array may help as well of course.

Comment: To make it a bit smarter, put the `Pattern`s in an `OrderedSet` and return the `Matcher` instead of a boolean.

Comment: I voted this down because this adds significantly to the processing overhead by including two separate tests, and because the OP asked how to rewrite a regular expression, opposed to what other ways can this be accomplished.

Comment: @Denomales Where did the OP ask how to rewrite the regular expressions? Are you sure you voted down objectively?

Comment: The question reads `How to remove such intersections and let it only detect by a[1] but not by a[0]`. Since a[1] and a[0] are both regular expressions and the OP says `let it only detect` strongly suggests they want a single regular expression.

Comment: I always got 9's for reading comprehension at school, but you must at least have gotten an 11...

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Use a negative look ahead to match `a[1]` `rs.150` format while at the same time preventing the `a[0]` `150` format.

Generic expression: `(?!  the a[0] regex goes here )  followed by the a[1] expression`

Basic regex statment: `(?![$£€]?\s*\d*[\.]?[pP]?\d*\d)Rs[.]?\s*[\d,]*[.]?\d*\d`

escaped for java: `(?![$£€]?\\s*\\d*[\\.]?[pP]?\\d*\\d)Rs[.]?\\s*[\\d,]*[.]?\\d*\\d`

[image]

Comment: Voted this down, you don't want to do this when the number of regular expressions is growing, which is likely in this use case. The regular expression will become *slightly less readable*.

Comment: @Owlstead, That is the nature of the regular expression language. Providing you understand the language then it is completely readable. Also to aid in readability you can include the `x` option to force the regex engine to ignore whitespace and comments.

Comment: Where did it say the number of expressions is growing? Are you sure you voted down objectively?

Comment: Oh, for goodness sake please keep on generating regular expressions like the one above, as long as I don't have to work with the code, I'm fully ok with it...

Comment: Besides: " let it only detect by `a[1]` but not by `a[0]`?". You are preventing `a[1]` to detect `a[0]`, but you are not preventing an `a[0]` match.